# python round numpy array with trailing 0 to a certain number of decimals

Tags: python, numpy, rounding, trailing

I have a np array `freq_vector` filled with floating numbers. For example `freq_vector[0][0]` is `200.00000000000003`

I want to limit it to 4 decimals, then convert it to string for other usage.

When I do `round(freq_vector[0][0], 4)`, the result is `200.0`, rather than `200.0000`

How can I get `200.0000`?

Comment: `200.0` is the proper result of the rounding. You will only get `200.0000` if you use string formatters such as `'{0:.4f}'.format(200.00000000000003)`.

Comment: Try `np.array2string(np.array(12.), precision=4, floatmode='fixed')`, or equivalent with `np.set_printoptions`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, `200.0000` is the same as `200.0`. Both are floating point numbers with the same value. Since you want to convert them to strings, you can use the format method, such as the following:

```
"{:.4f}".format(freq_vector[0][0])
```

Using the `round()` function is not necessary in this case.

In Python 3, you can use the simpler "f-string" syntax:

```
f"{freq_vector[0][0]:.4f}"
```

You can find more information about this feature at [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#format-specifiers).